# Cargar Table Dinamico atravez de jscript consumiendo un WebService asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Buenas Quisiera que me puedan ayudar les comento estoy realizando en un proyecto de webservice y pagina web, y se crea una tabla dinamica segun el json lo que vota pero cuando le pongo los parametros default si me logra salir bien pero en mi webservice cuando le coloco variables de entrada no me sale este son los dos codigos que puse uno como default y otro poniendo parametro quisiera que me puedan ayudar ya que me base gracias a este Autor:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-data-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery-datatables-plugin/

Tan solo que ese autor no le da variables de entrada y bueno yo si quise ponerlo y es donde ahi me sale ese error de la imagen .

Gracias

**Proyecto Webservice SIN VARIABLES DE ENTRADA**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void Usp_MostrarIncidentes()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_MostrarIncidentes", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = "";

        var students = new List<ListaIncidencias>();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var student = new ListaIncidencias
            {
                Minutos = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()),
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString()),
                Fecha = Convert.ToString(reader[2].ToString()),
                TipoIncidencia = reader[3].ToString(),
                Sub_TipoIncidencia = reader[4].ToString(),
                Estado = reader[5].ToString(),
                Ver = reader[6].ToString()

            };
            students.Add(student);
        }
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(students));
    }
```

**y en el Javascript llamado CargarTabla:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "../../Ws_MostrarIncidencias.asmx/Usp_MostrarIncidentes",
            success: function (data) {

                var datatableVariable = $('#TabIncidencias').DataTable({

                    data: data,
                    columns: [

                        { 'data': 'Minutos' },
                        { 'data': 'Id' },
                        { 'data': 'Fecha' },
                        { 'data': 'TipoIncidencia' },
                        { 'data': 'Sub_TipoIncidencia' },
                        { 'data': 'Estado' },
                        { 'data': 'Ver' }


                    ]
                });
                $('#TabIncidencias tfoot th').each(function () {
                    var placeHolderTitle = $('#TabIncidencias thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control input input-sm" placeholder = "Buscar ' + placeHolderTitle + '" />');
                });


                datatableVariable.columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                        column.search(this.value).draw();
                    });
                });
                $('.showHide').on('click', function () {
                    var tableColumn = datatableVariable.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                    tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

y en el html del asp.net

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AtenderIncidencia.aspx.cs" Inherits="SistemMesaAyuda.Heldesk.Incidencia.AtenderIncidencia" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/JsGlobal.js"></script>
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../js/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../css/Pagina.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../js/MostrarIncidencias.js"></script>

    <link href="../../DataTable/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../DataTable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <style>
        *
        {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .panel1
        {
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>Imagen/Qapaq.png" class="img" />
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Financiera QAPAQ</a>
                </div>
                <%--Menu de Opciones--%>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>Opciones.aspx">Regresar al menú principal </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><%= Session["Nombres"].ToString()%> </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <%--Panel de navegación--%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">

                            <div style="margin-top: 150px">

                                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                    <div class="panel-heading text-left">Lista Incidencia</div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">

                                        <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="TabIncidencias">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Aviso</th>
                                                    <th>Ticket</th>
                                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                                    <th>Tipo Incidencia</th>
                                                    <th>Sub-Tipo Incidencia</th>
                                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                                    <th>Ver</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Aviso</th>
                                                    <th>Ticket</th>
                                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                                    <th>Tipo Incidencia</th>
                                                    <th>Sub-Tipo Incidencia</th>
                                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                                    <th>Ver</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>

                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Que cuando lo ejecuto si me sale y se crea como una tabla dinamica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero cuando le doy variables de entrada que esto es en**

**webservice**

```
 [WebMethod]
        public void Usp_MostrarIncidentes(Int32 Opc, String Username)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_MostrarIncidentes", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Opc;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = Username;

            var students = new List<ListaIncidencias>();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var student = new ListaIncidencias
                {
                    Minutos = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()),
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString()),
                    Fecha = Convert.ToString(reader[2].ToString()),
                    TipoIncidencia = reader[3].ToString(),
                    Sub_TipoIncidencia = reader[4].ToString(),
                    Estado = reader[5].ToString(),
                    Ver = reader[6].ToString()

                };
                students.Add(student);
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(students));
        }

    }

**y esto en la pagina load** 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ws_MostrarIncidencias Objs = new Ws_MostrarIncidencias();
            Objs.Usp_MostrarIncidentes(1, Session["usuario"].ToString());
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Mostrar", "prueba();", true);
        }
```

y esto en javascript:

```
function prueba() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "../../Ws_MostrarIncidencias.asmx/Usp_MostrarIncidentes",
            success: function (data) {

                var datatableVariable = $('#TabIncidencias').DataTable({

                    data: data,
                    columns: [

                        { 'data': 'Minutos' },
                        { 'data': 'Id' },
                        { 'data': 'Fecha' },
                        { 'data': 'TipoIncidencia' },
                        { 'data': 'Sub_TipoIncidencia' },
                        { 'data': 'Estado' },
                        { 'data': 'Ver' }


                    ]
                });
                $('#TabIncidencias tfoot th').each(function () {
                    var placeHolderTitle = $('#TabIncidencias thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control input input-sm" placeholder = "Buscar ' + placeHolderTitle + '" />');
                });


                datatableVariable.columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                        column.search(this.value).draw();
                    });
                });
                $('.showHide').on('click', function () {
                    var tableColumn = datatableVariable.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                    tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
                });
            }
        });

    });
};
```

Bueno en el HTML sigue igual.

pero cuando ejecuto me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EL PROBLEMA ES CUANDO LE DOY PARAMETROS DE ENTRADA . QUISIERA QUE ME AYUDEN....**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno basicamente lo que realize :

1. en el webservice agrege las dos variables de entrada :

[WebMethod]
        public void Usp_MostrarIncidentes(Int32 opt,String username,Int32 IdAtencionTarea)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;

```
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_MostrarIncidentes", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = opt;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idatenciontarea", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = IdAtencionTarea;

        var students = new List<ListaIncidencias>();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var student = new ListaIncidencias
            {
                Minutos = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()),
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString()),
                Fecha = Convert.ToString(reader[2].ToString()),
                TipoIncidencia = reader[3].ToString(),
                Sub_TipoIncidencia = reader[4].ToString(),
                Estado = reader[5].ToString(),
                Ver = reader[6].ToString()

            };
            students.Add(student);
        }
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(students));

    }
```

Luego lo que realize es crear un pagina en blanco sin html donde en el codebing 
en el load colocaba este codigo:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ws_MostrarIncidencias Ws = new Ws_MostrarIncidencias();
            Ws.Usp_MostrarIncidentes(2, Session["usuario"].ToString(),0);
        }
```

y en el javascrip puse que consumiera de esa pagina ya que ahi me estaba generando el json :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
       // url: "../../Ws_MostrarIncidencias.asmx/Usp_MostrarIncidentes",
        url: "../../Heldesk/Incidencia/DefaultHeldesk.aspx/Usp_MostrarIncidentes",
        success: function (data) {

            var datatableVariable = $('#TabIncidencias').DataTable({

                data: data,
                columns: [

                    { 'data': 'Minutos' },
                    { 'data': 'Id' },
                    { 'data': 'Fecha' },
                    { 'data': 'TipoIncidencia' },
                    { 'data': 'Sub_TipoIncidencia' },
                    { 'data': 'Estado' },
                    { 'data': 'Ver' }


                ]
            });
            $('#TabIncidencias tfoot th').each(function () {
                var placeHolderTitle = $('#TabIncidencias thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control input input-sm" placeholder = "Buscar ' + placeHolderTitle + '" />');
            });


            datatableVariable.columns().every(function () {
                var column = this;
                $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                    column.search(this.value).draw();
                });
            });
            $('.showHide').on('click', function () {
                var tableColumn = datatableVariable.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
            });
        }
    });

});
```

en la pagina donde queria que se agrege solo en el html
coloque este codigo y funciono

```
 <script src="../../js/MostrarIncidencias.js"></script>
```